# Go install can't find my internal packages in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

So I'm trying to Dockerize my project which looks like this:

```
project/
  main.go
  package1/
  package2/
  package3/
```

And it also requires some outside packages such as github.com/gorilla/mux
Note my project is internal on a github.company.com domain so I'm not sure if that matters.
So here's my Dockerfile and yes, my GOPATH and GOROOT is set and PLEASE don't just tell me to read https://golang.org/doc/code.html. I have and am still am having this issue.

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###

FROM golang:1.10 as builder
WORKDIR /go/src/github.company.com/project-repo/project
COPY . .
RUN go get 
RUN go install <- ERROR HERE
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o executable -a -installsuffix cgo .

### STAGE 2: Setup ###

FROM python:3.6-alpine
COPY --from=builder /go/src/github.company.com/project-repo/project/executable /api/executable
CMD ["/api/executable"]
```

Then I run:

```
docker build -t myapp .
```

And get this error:

```
main.go: cannot find package github.company.com/project-repo/project/package1 in any of:
/usr/local/go/src/github.company.com/project-repo/project/package1 (from $GOROOT)
/go/src/github.company.com/project-repo/project/package1 (from $GOPATH)
```

And keep in mind those paths are correct. Why can't go install packages that are within itself?? Main.go imports package1, but for sure reason "go install" doesn't install packages inside itself..

Comment: When you run `docker build`, are you in the `project` directory, and is the `Dockerfile` there too?  Does adding `RUN ls` to the `Dockerfile` after the `COPY` give any helpful suggestions?

Comment: Yes I'm in the project main which besides main.go, it does make the Dockerfile and Makefile as well as package1/, package2/, and that reflects in ls

Comment: Does the import in main.go specifies the path like this: import github.company.com/project-repo/project/package1?

Comment: Yes yes it does! Does that help you?

Comment: I've tried /go/src/github.company.com/project-repo/project/package1. Maybe I need to drop the /go/src?

Comment: yes, it should be import github.company.com/project-repo/project/package1

Comment: Also could you add a 'RUN ls -al' after 'RUN go get' and provide the results here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176337/discussion-between-coco-bennett-and-jayachandran).

Answer (score 2):

Wow, golang really is picky about paths! It was just that I had assigned my working directory to the wrong place. There was another file in the tree:

```
WORKDIR /go/src/github.company.com/COMPANY/project-repo/project
```

Answer (score -1):

did you make(`mkdir`) the `WORKDIR` before setting its value?